# Entire function with $\int_{\mathbb C} |\log|f| |<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

That's an old qual problem:

> If $\log|f|$ is absolutely integrable (with respect to $\mathbb R^2$ Lebesgue measure) with $f$ entire, then prove that
>   $f$ is constant.

One can see that $\log(1/|f|)$ is also integrable. It is also easy to see that for all $\varepsilon$ the sets $\{z: 1-\varepsilon<|f|<1+\varepsilon \}$ have infinite measure, while the complement has finite. But I can't see how to proceed and use the the fact that $f$ is entire.

Also, close to the zeros of $f$, (e.g. $f(0)=0$) we have $f(z)=z^ng(z)$ where $g(0)\neq 0$, so $\log|f(z)|=n\log |z| |g(z)|$ and by passing to polar coordinates we see that $\log|f|$ is always integrable close to the zeros of $f$. Therefore, it suffices to look away from the zeros of $f$ or poles of $1/f$.

Comment: Do you know that $u:=\log |f|$ is subharmonic? If so, then the sub-mean-value property + Fubini do the job: $u(a)\le \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \iint_{|z-a|<r} u \to 0$ as $r\to\infty$. Hence $u\le 0$ everywhere, and  $|f|\le 1$.

Comment: That's nice! How can you prove though, that it is subharmonic?

Comment: If the theory of subharmonic functions was not developed in the course, then you are probably not expected to invent it during the exam. I suppose there is another solution.

Comment: Is there an easy way to prove the sub-mean value property specifically for $\log|f|$ without subharmonic functions theory? Locally it's true, but how can we prove it for all $r>0$?

Comment: Yes... [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_formula).

Comment: Thanks! If we assume that $|f(z_0)|>1$ for some $z_0$ then using Jensen it's done!

Comment: Cool. Please post an answer if it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_0\in \mathbb C$ with $f(z_0)\neq 0$. By Jensen's Formula
$$ \log |f(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log |f(z_0+re^{it})|dt$$
for all $r>0$. Mutiplying by $r$ and integrating from $0$ to $R$ yields
$$ \log|f(z_0)| \frac{R^2}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{R} \int_{0}^{2\pi} R| \log|f(z_0+re^{it})||dtdr$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{D(z_0,R)}|\log |f(z)||dA(z)$$
Therefore
$$\log|f(z_0)| \leq  \frac{1}{\pi R^2} \int_{\mathbb C} |\log|f(z)||dA(z)$$
for all $R>0$. Letting $R\to \infty$ gives 
$$\log|f(z_0)|\leq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow |f(z_0)|\leq 1$$
Thus, $f$ is bounded, and by Liouville it is constant.